# Toyota Starlet 4efe Runs Rich And Stalls

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, stall, starlet

I have a 1994 Starlet, 4EFE motor with no modifications. Intermittently it will flood itself with petrol and stall, when the engine is idling. And is hard to start again. This happens at operating temperature. I have fitted a new themostat. What things should I check for this?
Thanks in advance, Nick

Comment: I'm not familiar with that engine specifically -- is it carbureted? I noticed that you tagged the question Electrical -- any reason you think it's an electrical problem specifically?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a carburetor on that engine.  If so, check that the choke is working properly and also that the float or float valve is not stuck.